# Submenu works but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0, submenu

I'm building a website called [zorgenbijstand.nl](http://www.zorgenbijstand.nl/index.php)

I have made an submenu on "geschiedenis". This works fine, on all devices using firefox responsive design-mode. Now I have placed the site "live". On my iphone 6s the submenu won't select and close on click. I am doing something wrong, but what?
It's an joomla 3.7.0 site.

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Dropdown menu
    if ($('.parent').children('ul').length > 0) {
        $('.parent').addClass('dropdown');
        $('.parent > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
        $('.parent > a').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
        $('.parent > a').append('');
        $('.parent > ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a code. We shouldn't go to your website and find out where and how you wrote that part of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have insert the code.

Answer (score 0):

That script works fine. Works on iPhone and Android as well. but the problem coming from another part of the code.

When you are not in the `geschiedenis` page your main menu doesn't have `ul` submenu in it:

[image: no sub menu]

and what you have in `geschiedenis` page:

[image: ul that related to the submenu]

Then you know this `if` condition will always be `false`:

```
if ($('.parent').children('ul').length > 0)
```

because there isn't any `ul` child in it.